# \apptocmd into a conditional—why it does not work?

Tags: beamer, conditionals, etoolbox

Why the following MWE does not work while if I comment the conditional it works?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter

\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{

\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{\only<1>{\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1}}}%
{\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle succeeded **}}%
{\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle failed **}}%

}{}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
Hello \pause world
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use `\apptocmd` in the argument of another command.

Comment: @egreg thank you, so it's impossible to make any kind of if cycle with that command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Main answer

In general, patching commands when `#` is involved can't happen in the argument to another command. One can do some tricks with category codes, but another approach can be easier:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{\@tempswatrue}{\@tempswafalse}
\if@tempswa
  \usepackage{bookmark}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}
    {\only<1>{\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1}}}%
    {\message{** patching of \noexpand\beamer@@frametitle succeeded **}}%
    {\message{** patching of \noexpand\beamer@@frametitle failed **}}%
\fi
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
Hello \pause world
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The `\if@tempswa` conditional is a scratch conditional provided by the kernel.

Here's what's written in the `.log` file:

```
** patching of \beamer@@frametitle succeeded **
```

### Generalized answer

A similar approach without using `\@tempswa` and that can be used for other LaTeX pseudoconditionals such as `\@ifpackageloaded` or `\@ifundefined`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\latex@conditional}[1]{#1{11}{01}}

\if\latex@conditional{\@ifclassloaded{beamer}}
  \usepackage{bookmark}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}
  \apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}
    {\only<1>{\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1}}}%
    {\message{** patching of \noexpand\beamer@@frametitle succeeded **}}%
    {\message{** patching of \noexpand\beamer@@frametitle failed **}}%
%\else
% code for the false branch
\fi
\makeatother
```

This relies on the facts that `\if` expands tokens and that LaTeX pseudoconditionals are fully expandable; so in the end `\if` finds either `11` if the condition is true, otherwise `01` and so it follows the true and false branches accordingly. Note that such constructions can be nested in other TeX style conditionals. Code for the false branch can be specified, too.

### Alternative method

Alternatively, use the `regexpatch` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}{
  \usepackage{bookmark}
  \usepackage{regexpatch}
  \xapptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}
    {\only<1>{\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1}}}%
    {\message{** patching of \noexpand\beamer@@frametitle succeeded **}}%
    {\message{** patching of \noexpand\beamer@@frametitle failed **}}%
}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
Hello \pause world
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```